# Add node after some node or to the parent in XmlToLinq in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have structure like this one

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <item>
            <value>1</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <value>3</value>
        </item>
    </parent>
</root>
```

Now I want to add a new item with value 2. I want to add it in the correct position. My linq looks like this one:

```
xDoc.Root
    .Element("parent")
    .Elements("item")
    .Where(i => i.Element("value").Value < 2)
    .LastOfDefault()
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("item", new XElement("value", 2)));
```

and this works fine with that structure.

But this would fail with NullReferenceException if there is no elements in parent:

```
<root>
    <parent>
    </parent>
</root>
```

In this case I want just to add this element to the the parent node. How this can be done with less blood?

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to verify that the an item is found first before you attempt to add it.  Fortunately C# 6 adds null conditional operators to make expressing this nice.

```
doc.Elements("root").Elements("parent").Elements("item")
    .OrderBy(i => (int)i.Element("value"))
    .LastOrDefault(i => (int)i.Element("value") < 2)
    ?.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("item", new XElement("value", 2)));
```

If you're using an older version, just check explicitly.

```
var last = doc.Elements("root").Elements("parent").Elements("item")
    .OrderBy(i => (int)i.Element("value"))
    .LastOrDefault(i => (int)i.Element("value") < 2);
if (last != null)
    last.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("item", new XElement("value", 2)));
```